# Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations circular reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've been wasting two days now to try solve this problem but have yet to find a solution.

In my code that saves an entity with a relationship, I get this error when reaching `ctx.SaveChanges()`:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.
>   Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model
>   requirements, or store-generated values.

*Shipment.cs*

```
[ForeignKey("ShipmentNumber")]
public int? DefaultShipmentNumber { get; set; }

public virtual ShipmentNumber ShipmentNumber { get; set; }
```

*ShipmentNumber.cs*

```
[Column("shipment_id")]
[ForeignKey("Shipment")]
public byte ShipmentId { get; set; }

public virtual Shipment Shipment { get; set; }
```

To avoid circular references, ShipmentNumber belonging to Shipment is nullable (optional), whereas ShipmentNumber's dependency on Shipment is required.

I first create a Shipment, add it and then attach a ShipmentNumber to it and add it to table as well.

Here's the fluent API code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Shipment>()
    .HasOptional<ShipmentNumber>((shipment) => shipment.ShipmentNumber)
    .WithMany();
```

Shipment has one "true" ShipmentNumber, but many ShipmentNumbers can link to the same Shipment, hence the `WithMany()` call (relation without a navigator property). In theory, both relations should always return one entity, but I know EF won't allow me a 1:1 relation here, so I'm using optional.

Here's the actual code:

```
shipment = tracker.Shipment;

ctx.Shipments.Add(shipment);
shipment.ShipmentNumber = new ShipmentNumber { Number = tracker.ShipmentNumber };

ctx.ShipmentNumbers.Add(shipment.ShipmentNumber);

ctx.SaveChanges();
```

If someone knows how to make it properly save the entity along with the relation, please do tell. I'm totally stuck at the moment.

Comment: You said 'Shipment has one "true" ShipmentNumber, but many ShipmentNumbers can link to the same Shipment, hence the WithMany() call (relation without a navigator property).' I don't understand... 1 Shipment has 1 ShipmentNumber OR 1 Shipment has N ShipmentNumber? Your fluent mapping shows 1:n, but your classes shows 1:0.1

Comment: @FabioLuz Thanks for replying. Yes, in the database, there may be multiple ShipmentNumbers belonging to the same Shipment, but in the model, I only want it to return one ShipmentNumber and vice versa. I can get it to fetch all Shipments and all relations are correct. It's only when I try to save things to DB where things fail. How am I to define my relations in the model otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't know why you want a 1:n relationship in database and a 1:0.1 relationship in the model.

**Case 1**

If you want to make a 1:1 relationship, you should declare your model as follows:

```
public class Shipment
{
    public int ShipmentId { get; set; }  

    //NO FK here

    public virtual ShipmentNumber ShipmentNumber { get; set; }
}

public class ShipmentNumber
{
    public int ShipmentId { get; set; } //ShipmentNumber PK is Also Shipment FK

    public virtual Shipment Shipment { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Shipment>()
    .HasKey(i => i.ShipmentId);

modelBuilder.Entity<ShipmentNumber>()
    .HasKey(i => i.ShipmentId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Shipment>()
    .HasRequired(i => i.ShipmentNumber)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(i => i.Shipment)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Generated Migration:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Shipments",
    c => new
        {
            ShipmentId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.ShipmentId);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.ShipmentNumbers",
    c => new
        {
            ShipmentId = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.ShipmentId)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Shipments", t => t.ShipmentId)
    .Index(t => t.ShipmentId);
```

**Case 2**

If you want to make a 1:n relationship:

```
public class Shipment
{
    public int ShipmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ShipmentNumber> ShipmentNumbers { get; set; }
}

public class ShipmentNumber
{
    public int ShipmentNumberId { get; set; }

    public int ShipmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Shipment Shipment { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Shipment>()
    .HasKey(i => i.ShipmentId);

modelBuilder.Entity<ShipmentNumber>()
    .HasKey(i => i.ShipmentNumberId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Shipment>()
    .HasMany(i => i.ShipmentNumbers)
    .WithRequired(i => i.Shipment)
    .HasForeignKey(i => i.ShipmentId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Generated Migration:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Shipments",
    c => new
        {
            ShipmentId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.ShipmentId);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.ShipmentNumbers",
    c => new
        {
            ShipmentNumberId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            ShipmentId = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.ShipmentNumberId)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Shipments", t => t.ShipmentId)
    .Index(t => t.ShipmentId);
```

Another problem is the code you are using to add items to database.

```
ctx.Shipments.Add(shipment);
shipment.ShipmentNumber = new ShipmentNumber { Number = tracker.ShipmentNumber };

//this line is not necessary
ctx.ShipmentNumbers.Add(shipment.ShipmentNumber);

ctx.SaveChanges();
```

When you add a new `Shipment` all dependant objects will be inserted to database, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code you provided. I haven't tried it yet. So if I'm using the 1:n relation (Case 2), how do I access the "true" ShipmentNumber from Shipment? A `Where` or `Join` query?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what do you mean with "true" Shipment Number. Could you explain me?

Comment: There are variants of the ShipmentNumber belonging to the Shipment, but only one is "official", for a better way of putting it, hence the one-to-many/one-to-one relationship

Comment: What if you put a boolean property in `ShipmentNumber`, which will tell whether it is the "official" or not? Then, you could use a `Where` query to retrieve only the `ShipmentNumber` that is the 'official'

Comment: Good idea! I'll try that. I'm getting an error now `Unknown column 'Extent1.ShipmentNumber_Id' in 'field list'`, it seems it can't find my foreign key? I can't really use the name `ShipmentId` on my `Shipment` model, it has to be named `Id`

Comment: Just change the name of the property in the model and mapping. Remember to add a new migraiton

Comment: Still not working... Was your Case 2 fluent code somehow wrong?

Comment: I tried here, and it worked fine. Maybe you are missing something. Take a look at generated migration. Update your question explaining the error.

Comment: I managed to solve that error. But I'm now I'm getting `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ("posten"."shipment_numbers", CONSTRAINT "FK_shipment_numbers_shipments" FOREIGN KEY ("shipment_id") REFERENCES "shipments" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE)`. Why does it have to be so hard to insert a record and its relation? Looks like both `id` (Shipment) and `shipment_id` (ShipmentNumber) is 0.

Comment: If you are not providing any id, they should be configured to be generated by sql server. `modelBuilder.Entity<Shipment>().Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);` You should do this to all fields that must be auto-incremented. Remember that you don't have to add the related entities to their dbset.   Once you add a new entity to its dbset, all related new entities will be inserted too.

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick :) I think the naming is really unintuitive though, how did they get `AUTO_INCREMENT` to `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)`?

Comment: It is because the term "auto-increment" is not used for sql server. There is no "auto-increment" in sql server, different from MySQL. SQL Server uses "Identity", so EF uses Identity too. Don't forget to mark the post as answer, to help future people.